# Could not load control AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am trying to use the AjaxToolKit Editor, but when I view the page I get an error saying the control was not loaded correctly.

Since I'm not sure what is missing, I'm not sure how much information to provide in this post.  If there's something else I can provide that could point to the problem, please advise and I will add it.

My error message:

```
Could not load control AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor. The
script reference(s) of this control was not loaded correctly. If
AjaxControlToolkit.config is used, probably this control is not
registered properly.    Description: An unhandled exception occurred
during the execution of the current web request. Please review the
stack trace for more information about the error and where it
originated in the code.   Exception Details: System.Exception: Could
not load control AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor. The script
reference(s) of this control was not loaded correctly. If
AjaxControlToolkit.config is used, probably this control is not
registered properly. Source Error:   An unhandled exception was
generated during the execution of the current web request. Information
regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified
using the exception stack trace below.   Stack Trace:  [Exception:
Could not load control AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.Editor. The
script reference(s) of this control was not loaded correctly. If
AjaxControlToolkit.config is used, probably this control is not
registered properly.]   
AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +387 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +83   
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168   
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +168   
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+974
```

My HTML:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="UACWeb.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="AjaxToolKitTag" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>TEST</title>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <AjaxToolKitTag:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" CombineScripts="false"></AjaxToolKitTag:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <cc1:Editor ID="Editor1" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Controls section of my Web.config:

```
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
  </controls>
```

I do not have a AjaxControlToolkit.config file.

Comment: Can you get rid of the second registration of the AjaxControlToolkit, and change cci to ajaxtoolkittag?

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research I have discovered that a number of users are having problems with the April, June, & July 2013 release of the Ajax Toolkit involving a reference to the stand-alone HTML editor control. I tried "jumping through hoops" by editing my `web.config` and adding an `ajaxtoolkit.config` file to the root which many have mentioned fixes this issue, but none of those solutions seemed to resolve the problem for me. I have however, discovered a way to resolve the issue for the web projects I am working on myself.

I downloaded and reinstalled the [January 2013 version of Ajax Control Toolkit](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/100852). It appears that this version of the toolkit does not contain the HTML editor reference issue like the current versions do.

Here's what I did:

1. I deleted the Ajax Toolkit DLLs from the `bin\` directory, removed the July 2013 Ajax Toolkit references from the solution, and removed the Ajax Toolkit controls from the toolbox.
2. I then copied the January 2013 version of the Ajax Toolkit DLLs to the `bin\` directory, added the January 2013 version back to the toolbox, and ran the project, which now runs without any of the previous reference errors I was getting.

I believe sticking with the January 2013 version of the Ajax Control Toolkit is the workaround for all of our projects until someone figures out exactly what is causing this and how to fix it in the more current Ajax Toolkit versions.

Comment: have you tried Dec 2013 version? I am having same issue with Dec 2013 release.